# Consume java web service from .NET Web Service and/or asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, pfx

I'm trying to consume a Java Web Service from third party, so i dont have any control over it. I have a pfx file which is password protected, and i installed it in my development box.
This is the code i'm using:

```
var proxy = new   MyServiceReference.WsaaServerBeanService();
var result = proxy.login("test");
```

I'm getting **System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.TimedOut** exception when invoking the login web method. The first thing that come to my mind is an authentication issue. Apart from installing the pfx, do i need to send some other info to the web server to authenticate?

Comment: JAVA has nothing to do with this. One main advantage of a web service is that it doesn't matter how it was implemented as long as the web service follows standard web protocols. HTTP is HTTP and JSON is JSON.

Comment: Thats right @JonathanHenson, that why i not tagged this with Java ;) The problem is that i'm able to create the proxy but not invoke the web service methods

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.TimedOut
```

Does not indicate an authentication issue, it indicates that you either are not able to contact the remote web service endpoint, or you are and the service is taking too long to respond. Make sure you can actually hit the endpoint from your machine via telnet, a web browser etc...

Authentication failures will usually return immediately.